# Video Wall Mount in the home

Tags: walls, mounting, installation, television, mount

Anyone installed a video wall mount for non-commercial TV. I was thinking to purchase an MV70 Video Wall mount because it is fixed and easy to pull out and push back into the canvas.

Your thoughts and recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Can you use Commercial mounts for homes, specially am looking at the MV70 Video Wall mount.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you use Commercial mounts for homes?

Yes, I know of no law that says a product made to withstand the rigors of commercial use can not be used in a house or apartment.

I think the Commercial classification on this is mostly because the market for video walls is mainly a commercial one. **I.E.** Not a lot of home owners are building video walls.

Comment: While this is true in this case, and likely in many other cases, there are exceptions (the main one being garage door openers -- it is indeed illegal to use a commercial opener in a residential setting, due to peculiarities of the applicable UL standard)

Comment: oh I see, I would of never thought of that